# 'Shadow tabs' on Safari?

Tags: mac, safari

I'm not sure what the name of this feature is or what it does, but it confuses me, and I was wondering if I could disable it. Sometimes I have a Safari window open with multiple tabs. For a long time, I would click the name of the tab at the top, and drag that tab somewhere else, and it would give the tab its own window. But now, sometimes when I do this (I am not sure what triggers when this does or does not happen), I get two copies of the tab, one with a shadow over it. If I try to close the shadow tab on the original window, the second copy of the tab just goes back to being a new tab. What is this feature, and how can I disable it? Here's a screenshot of what I mean; this resulted from me just dragging this tab away to try and give it its own window.

Edit: Other people are reporting this as a bug, c.f. https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/xhqjgl/safari_16_dragging_out_tabs/

[image: example of safari bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I suspect this is a bug, it isn't a memory leak since that wouldn't cause a behavior like this.

If you have two windows open with the same tab group selected, each tab is shown in both window. To avoid conflicts, the tabs are linked, so you'll see this behavior if you open the same tab in the same tab group in two windows.

I suspect that somehow you're triggering the creation of two linked tabs unintentionally. I was able to reproduce this shortly, but then it stopped happening.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like memory leak to me. Wait for Apple's official fix.

Comment: What? Why do you think this is a memory leak? That usually just causes increased memory usage. I'm able to reproduce this on my machine too.